# How to check if file exists on upload?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, iformfile

I am building a small file upload application in ASP.NET Core 6. This is the code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync(List<IFormFile> files)
{
foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about checking if the file already exists on the server? FormFile does not have an `File.Exists(path)` method such as the File class

Thanks!

Comment: [`Path.GetTempFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=net-6.0) gets a new unique temp file name, it won't exist on the server already. Or do you mean is there a file somewhere with the same content as what is being uploaded?

Comment: Hey @Igor thanks. What I mean is how do I avoid uploading the same file twice? Ideally I would want to send a message to the UI giving the user the option to either cancel the upload or overwrite the existing file

Comment: You will need to build some type of key and way to persist that key. What that key is depends on what is being uploaded (type of data structure), that is a business decision. How to persist depends on how data is organized. Could be as simple as naming the file on disk or perhaps tracking it in a data store like a relational database or a nosql database.

Comment: @Igor I see. So if I use the same file name that could also work as the key. But how do I even access what is on the server? I guess I'm stuck thinking in File.Exists(...) terms

Comment: `File.Exists` could work after all you are using File.Create already.

Comment: @Igor Yes! thank you!!